# I want to get text from "aria-label" by python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

```
try:
    Rating = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.b5cd09854e.d10a6220b4')
except:
    Rating = None
Rating1 = []
for i in Rating:
    store = {
        'Rating': i.get_attribute("[aria-label]")
    }
    Rating1.append(store)
print(Rating1)
```

**Output**

`<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="867a6f4433baacd665edd311671faa81", element="69d53b22-5d2e-4e1a-8f55-682affc043b1")>`

I want scrape data from a website but I can't extract `"aria-label"` web elements text by python selenium.  please experts help me to extract `"aria-label"` web elements to get text from it.
fix it and rewrite

Answer (score 1):

so to get hold of the text you just use the `.text`.

Like so:-

```
Rating = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.b5cd09854e.d10a6220b4')
    
for i in Rating:
   print(i.text)
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

just use () instead of also using [] inside ().

So your code should be like this. .

```
try:
    Rating =driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.b5cd09854e.d10a6220b4')
except:
    Rating = None
Rating1 = []
for i in Rating:
    store = {
        'Rating': i.get_attribute("aria-label")
    }
    Rating1.append(store)
print(Rating1)
```